# Problems compiliing c++ code using cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, compilation, fcntl

I am trying to compile some source code in cygwin (in windows 7)
and get the following error when I run the make file

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -O2 -MT libcommon_a  Fcntl.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcommon_a-Fcntl.Tpo -c -o libcommon_a-Fcntl.o `test -f 'Fcntl.cpp' || echo './'`Fcntl.cpp
Fcntl.cpp: In function int setCloexec(int):
Fcntl.cpp:8: error: 'F_GETFD' was not declared in this scope
Fcntl.cpp:8: error: 'fcntl' was not declared in this scope
Fcntl.cpp:11: error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' was not declared in this scope
Fcntl.cpp:12: error: 'F_SETFD' was not declared in this scope
make[4]: *** [libcommon_a-Fcntl.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/abyss-1.1.2/Common'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/abyss-1.1.2'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/abyss-1.1.2'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Martin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/abyss-1.1.2_1'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

The problem file is:-

```
#include "Fcntl.h"
#include <fcntl.h>


/* Set the FD_CLOEXEC flag of the specified file descriptor. */
int setCloexec(int fd)
{
 int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
 if (flags == -1)
  return -1;
 flags |= FD_CLOEXEC;
 return fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags);
}
```

I don't understand what is going on,
the file fcntl.h is available and the varaiables that it says were not declared in this scope
do not give an error when I compile the file on its own

Any help would be much appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: May be because of name collision, like on win `fcntl.h` and `Fcntl.h` point to the same files and (I don't think this is the case, but stil...) you could be actually including the same file - check your include directories settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've not built things with Cygwin, so this might be off-base, but considering that you're building on Windows, which has a case-insensitive filesystem, are you sure that the compiler can tell the difference between your header `Fcntl.h` and the system header `fcntl.h`? It might just be including your header twice and never getting the system header.

Comment: You're on target.  FAT32 and NTFS is case-preserving, but not case-sensitive.  As such, you can't have a Makefile and a makefile in the same directory, since they would be considered ambiguous.  Or, in this case, when searching for "Fcntl.h", it finds the system <fctnl.h> just like the <fcntl.h> search does.  You'll want to rename Fcntl.h in the source directory to myFcntl.h and adjust the include appropriately.  (Leave the system fcntl.h alone.)

Answer (score 1):

What's up with those `#include` statements?  It seems like you have a header file in your project called `Fcntl.h`, is that right?  Does it have include guards in it?  If it does, maybe you're accidentally using the same guard as the built-in header, and as a result not getting its contents.  Cygwin normally runs on a case-insensitive filesystem, so even giving those headers similar names like that is probably dangerous.